# react - create an active class when onClick on child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, state

i'm using Meteor/ReactJS and i'm building a TodoList with lists. When a user click on a list item, I display the tasks associated to this list.
I can get the items, I'm calling the onClick with a parent function.
The problem is I would like to add an "active" class to the list item I just clicked. But I don't know how to do it on the parent class or neither in the child..

**Here is the parent class** (i'm calling this function in the render():

```
selectList(listId) {
    this.setState({ listSelected: listId });
}

renderLists() {
    return this.props.lists.map((list) => (
        <List 
            selectList={() => this.selectList(list._id)}
            key={list._id}
            list={list}
        />
    ));
}
```

**and here is the child:**

```
render() {
    return (
        <ListGroupItem onClick={this.props.selectList}>
            {this.props.list.name}
            <span className="pushRight">
                <Glyphicon 
                    onClick={() => this.deleteThisList()}
                    glyph="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
                />
            </span>
        </ListGroupItem>
    );
}
```

How could I get the result of selectList in parent and then give the class to the child, or How could I handle the click in the child and give the class directly in the child ?

Thanks a lot for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Parent**

1.pass selected id to **List** comp

```
selectList(listId) {
    this.setState({ listSelected: listId });
}

renderLists() {
    return this.props.lists.map(list => (
        <List
          selectedItemId={this.state.listSelected}
          selectList={() => this.selectList(list._id)}
          key={list._id}
          list={list}
        />
    ));
}
```

**Child**

2.Compare **list.id** with passed **selectedItemId**, if true, so this item is active

```
render() {
  const { selectList, list, selectedItemId} = this.props;
    return (
        <ListGroupItem isActive={list.id==selectedItemId} onClick={selectList}>
          {list.name}
          <span className="pushRight">
            <Glyphicon
              onClick={() => this.deleteThisList()}
              glyph="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
                />
          </span>
        </ListGroupItem>
    );
}
```

3.then in **ListGroupItem**

```
  render(){
      const {isActive}=this.props;
        return (
          <div className={"someclass "+(isActive? 'active':'')}>
            .......
          </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: I just edited few things cause ListGroupItem is react bootstrap element, now it's working perfectly, thank you very much @Utro! :D

Comment: I'm glad it helped ! :)